# My python discord bot is sending messages oddly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ok so the basic jist of my goal is that I'm trying to me a manageable list to help organize theme names in a discord server. My code should let me look at a list edit the list and show it again. The issue comes in when my bot tries to send the updated list through. Here's my code and my issue.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

FreeExtras = []

@client.command()
async def Free0(ctx):
    await ctx.send(FreeExtras)

@client.command()
async def addextra(ctx):
    name = await client.wait_for('message',check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel)
    FreeExtras.append(name)
```

When I try to show the list after editing my bot sends this:

> [<Message id=804880602042073118 channel= type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=306814779358445570 name='Gundamn' discriminator='0657' bot=False nick=None guild=> flags=>]

Comment: For `Free0` to work, I think you have to convert the list to a string, use `str(FreeExtras)` instead of `FreeExtras` inside the `send()` function. It looks like the message being send is a `discord.Message` object and not the content, however it looks like you haven't posted the function for that command. You'll have to get the content from the object using `Message.content`.

Answer (score 1):

`wait_for('message')` returns a `Message` object, you need to append its `content` via `.content`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

FreeExtras = []

@client.command()
async def Free0(ctx):
    await ctx.send(FreeExtras)

@client.command()
async def addextra(ctx):
    global FreeExtras
    name = await client.wait_for('message',check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel)
    FreeExtras.append(name.content)
```